# Fixed size div?

Tags: html

I want a normal div for the body of my text and a bunch of little divs that are exactly 150px by 150px. How might i do this?

Comment: The answer is soo straight-forward that I think that there's more into your question. What exactly have you tried? What exactly is the problem you have with it? Do you probably want to float them all left?

Answer (score 21):

This is a fairly trivial effect to accomplish. One way to achieve this is to simply place floated `div` elements within a common parent container, and set their width and height. In order to clear the floated elements, we set the `overflow` property of the parent.

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="cube">do</div>
    <div class="cube">ray</div>
    <div class="cube">me</div>
    <div class="cube">fa</div>
    <div class="cube">so</div>
    <div class="cube">la</div>
    <div class="cube">te</div>
    <div class="cube">do</div>
</div>
```

The CSS resembles the strategy outlined in the first paragraph above:

```css
.container {
    width: 450px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.cube {
    float: left;
    width: 150px; 
    height: 150px;
}
```

You can see the end result here: http://jsfiddle.net/Qjum2/2/

Browsers that support pseudo elements provide an alternative way to clear:

```css
.container::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```

You can see the results here: http://jsfiddle.net/Qjum2/3/

I hope this helps.

Comment: There, Clearing BR now. Less bleeding of the eyes? :)

Comment: no, worse! any time you use a clearing element it's awful code bloat. learn how to clear floats!

Comment: Oh goodness... This hardly counts as "code bloat." You're just being dramatic now ;)

Comment: no i'm serious.. it's one of my developer pet peeves. what happens if you change your stylesheet and your "cubes" are no longer floated? now you have a random "clear" div that does nothing. this is the same as creating a div class called "redLeftColumn"

Comment: You dont need an extra div with class clear. Its an unwanted extra markup you are adding it up. You can do the following:


:before, :after {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container:after,.container:before
{
content: " ";
display: table;
}

.container:after{
 clear: both;
}

Answer (score 11):

You can also hard code in the dimensions in your html code as opposed to putting the desired dimensions in a style sheet

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    <div id="mydiv" style="height:150px; width:150px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: here is the example code: 

<div id="maindiv">
   <div id="myDiv" style="width:150px; height:150px;">
   </div>
</div>

Comment: doesn't mean it doesn't work. if you are a total newbie (and since this question doesn't seem to have any knowledge of css, they might be), this is a viable temporary option while just learning html.

Comment: It also can be a handy tactic if you want to customize a div that is in a class, but don't want to effect other divs that are in that class. 1990's or logical and crafty to an extent?

Comment: Probably the best way to customize a classed div would to add an id in the class:<div id="custom" class="mydiv"> that way you can specify the customizations you want in the id and that will over ride what you don't want from the class. The hard coding would be good if you don't know about css I suppose.

Comment: You don't need to do style="" by the way

Answer (score 5):

As reply to Jonathan Sampson, this is the best way to do it, without a clearing div:

```
.container { width:450px; overflow:hidden }
.cube { width:150px; height:150px; float:left }

<div class="container">
    <div class="cube"></div>
    <div class="cube"></div>
    <div class="cube"></div>
    <div class="cube"></div>
    <div class="cube"></div>
    <div class="cube"></div>
    <div class="cube"></div>
    <div class="cube"></div>
    <div class="cube"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.myDiv { height: 150px; width 150px; }

<div class="mainDiv">
   <div class="myDiv"></div>
   <div class="myDiv"></div>
   <div class="myDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If he's asking this question, he might want a bit more detail. You can do it with `<div style="width:150px;height:150px"></div>` right in the HTML (not recommended) or do what Jason said but you have to give your div a class, like `<div class="myDiv">`...

Comment: i'm answering the question the OP asked.

Comment: LOL yes Jason did answer it and all i needed to know was height exist and does apply to div's

Comment: ...so why didn't you pick my answer as the one that answered your question? or even vote it up? lol...?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `height` and `width` of your `divs` with `css`.

```
<style type="text/css">
.box {
     height: 150px;
     width: 150px;
}
</style>
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="normal>text..</div>
<div id="small1" class="smallDiv"></div>
<div id="small2" class="smallDiv"></div>
<div id="small3" class="smallDiv"></div>
```

css:

```
.smallDiv { height: 150px; width: 150px; }
```